# NHibernate N+1 issue when building menu in Spark View Engine ASP.NET MVC

Tags: nhibernate, eager-loading, spark-view-engine

I have a website with 1000's of categories. I'm building a menu that lists the root categories and on hover shows the child categories (and perhaps one level more).

In my spark view I have this:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li each="var category in categories">
            ${Html.ActionLink(category.Name, "Index", "Category", new {id=category.Id}, new {@class="drop"})}
            <div class="dropdown_1column">
                <div class="col_1 firstcolumn">
                    <ul class="levels">
                        <li each="var subcategory1 in category.ChildCategories">
                            ${Html.ActionLink(subcategory1.Name, "Index", "Category", new {id=subcategory1.Id}, new {@class="drop"})}                            
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

In my category repository I have this:

```
var categories = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Category))
                .Add(Restrictions.IsEmpty("ParentCategories")).Add(!Restrictions.Eq("Name", "Hide"))
                .AddOrder(Order.Asc(sortBy))
                .SetFetchMode("ParentCategories", FetchMode.Eager)
                .List<Category>();
```

I'm getting an N+1 alert in NHProfiler when the spark view engine is looping through the child categories. Because the child categories are lazyload'ed it NHibernate fires a select for every child category of each root category.
If I set the ChildCategories FetchMode to Eager then NH traverses all the way down each child category which obviously causes a huge select. 
I'm looking for a way to eager load only the requires child categories or otherwise contain it in one roundtrip.

I've been reading [this post](http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/01/eager-fetch-multiple-child-collections-in-1-round-trip-with-nhibernate/), but it doesn't really offer a solution as far as I can see.

Any ideas?

http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/01/eager-fetch-multiple-child-collections-in-1-round-trip-with-nhibernate/

Comment: Could the subcategories be pulled (and the cached) with an Ajax request once the user actually mouses over them instead of sending them all down to the client on first page load?  If there are thousands (as you say) you might be sending along a lot of unnecessary markup.

Comment: True. Might be a good way to go. Shame you didn't put this in an answer. Can't mark comments as accepted ;)

Comment: Wasn't an answer to your question per se, just a suggestion about a different way to approach it.  This way someone else who's trying to get child elements to load properly will find a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HQL to load multiple levels of children.

```
var categoriesQuery = session.CreateQuery(@"select cat from Category cat join fetch cat.Children subCat join fetch subCat.Children").Future<Category>();

categoriesQuery.ToList(); // exec
```

One caveat to this approach is that NH is true to the database result so you will get duplicates in your outer lists if they're not mapped with AsSet.

If they're not you can issue each query separately using the future method. They'll still be batched.